# Google API: Authenticating with oauth user id

Tags: authentication, oauth, google-api, server-side

After google user authenticates on my web site, using Google JS API, I get users email, name, user id, etc.
I was looking for a way to store the user on my server side and recognize him/her next time he comes back.

Solution I found was saying: "user ID is the only thing you'll need to store in the database to authenticate a user with your web framework".

But I noticed, that google user id never changes, furthermore, you can see each users id on google plus for example. That means, my website users could easily be impersonated. What should I use to authenticate my google oauth users against server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the users `access_token` and send it to the server.
2. Have the server make a request to the [tokeninfo](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#tokeninfo-validation) endpoint.
3. Store the `user_id` response to correlate the user with future requests.

The `access_token` is a secret known only to the currently authenticated user and as long as it works you can assume the API response coming from Google belongs to that user.

Comment: I was hoping I could work this out without having oauth libs on the server side, but it seems like I can not.
Since I am having a rest api and I do not want to do external authentication calls on every request, I will go with following:
1) Get users access_token on client and send it to sever
2) Validate auth_token against external oauth service
3) Get user's data and register him/her if needed
4) Generate a random user specific token. Respond with it
5) Verify the server-generated-token with all the following request.